# Regular expression, how do i extract part of string VBscript

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a string which i need to extract a date from

```
 "01T00:00:00+02:00","quoteCreateDate":"2018-04-
 18T14:53:19+02:00","user":"Test_User","quoteNumber":"a9a3e413-4f40-4e00-a9ea-
 e5590a73968e","schemeCode":"7005227","totalPremium":66,"totalWaiverDeathDisabil
 ityPremium":6,"totalWaiverRetirementPremium":10,"roleplayers":
 [{"type":"natural","roleP"
```

i just need the folowing date "2018-04-18" after quotecreatedate

i tried the following , but it doesn't seem to work

```
Response = above string
set reg = new RegExp
reg.global = true
reg.pattern = ":(.*?)T"
Response = reg.replace(Response, "")
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it part of a JSON structure? Are there spaces between `04-` and `18`?

Comment: Yes it is. and no, theres no space between 04- and 18.